# `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null` - angular test with jest

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-test

I am getting an error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null` on testing the component. here is my code :

```
describe('SubSystemComponent', () => {

    let component: SubSystemComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubSystemComponent>;
    let store: Store<ModelPFServices>;


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SubSystemComponent],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                StoreModule.forRoot({}, { runtimeChecks: { strictStateImmutability: true, strictActionImmutability: true } }),
                StoreModule.forFeature('pfservice', reducer),
                EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
                EffectsModule.forFeature([EffectsSubSystem])
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();

        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();


    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubSystemComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        spyOn(component.ssRemoved, 'emit');
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should delete a id', () => {
//this part shows error
        const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
        const button = nativeElement.querySelector('.delete-item');
        button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
        fixture.detectChanges();

    });

});
```

what is wrong with my code or how to fix this? any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the store service in configureTestingModule within imports sentence, because now you are getting a null service. The function TestBed.get(store) is returning null

Comment: i am passing the service already right `StoreModule.forFeature('pfservice', reducer),`